# task scheduler in system settings does not appear

Tags: cron, system-settings, schedule

i install  [KDE's Task Scheduler](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kde-config-cron/)  to be able to access to crontab via GUI .

After install , i try to open this soft , however , i cannot find where it is. 
I follow this [DEMO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjW68yrUAWY) on Youtube , and i note that i can access on it via `System Settings`
[image]
However, When i open this interface , i don't find Task Scheduler in Menu , See the following screen shot.
[image]

Comment: The kde-config-cron is a KDE configuration module. The KDE modules are show in the KDE System Settings. Your image is not from the KDE System Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnome-schedule` is an alternative for task scheduler in KDE.Run the below command on terminal to install `gnome-schedule`,

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

Comment: Note this question was posted 3 years and 7 months ago  --> gnome-scheduler has been deprecated.  Now in August 2017, with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, here is a Q&A describing this situation:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/942401/how-to-control-cron-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts